# Dividend in Index fund in India

Tags: india, dividends, index-fund

Do the customers get dividend on investing in Index fund in India?
I searched on net but could not find anything useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes index funds do give dividends. However this is slightly different from normal mutual funds.

An index fund would have invested in stocks and all the dividends given by the underlying stocks is accumulated through the year and distributed once a year.

Comment: Thanx for the help!